# Are there spells that heal both me and my allies based on the damage dealt to our enemies?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, healing

I would like to create a character in D&D 5e similar to World of Warcraft's Shadow Priest. Specifically one aspect of the Shadow Priest; when he does damage, it heals other players nearby.

I was planning to create a Death Cleric to achieve this and use [*vampiric touch*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/vampiric-touch), but it heals only me. Is there a possibility to link others to me so they would get same amount of healing?

Comment: I've made an edit to the title to reflect the main body text a bit better. Hopefully I've preserved the intent of your question so please check the edit I've made and if it has changed what you're trying to ask please feel free to roll it back or change it further.

Comment: Thanks. I think the title portrays 1 possibility. Another would be to link 2 characters and whatever healing 1 receives, the linked one also receives. It can be even if another character heals me, I heal automatically someone linked to me.

So it can be combination of something that links and Vampiric Touch together.

Comment: We have a one question per post policy so if you would like to ask about both possibilities then you're more than welcome to post the other separately (you can change the title of this one back to how you had it or ask that as the new question and leave this one as-is, it's up to you). Do note that if you do ask the other question it *does* actually have to be different to this one. You can include a link to this question in your other question to help provide context but copy/pasting and only changing the title might cause users to think it's a duplicate. Hopefully all of that makes sense :)

Comment: Does it have to be one spell? Or combination of several?

Comment: @AntiDrondert it can be combination of several

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few class features that would permit this kind of playstyle to a limited degree, but first, it might be important to emphasize the elephant in the room, as it were.

## Healing in 5th Edition D&D is more limited than in games like World of Warcraft

This mostly comes down to some fundamental design decisions. D&D 5e places an emphasis on each character having limited resources—much more limited than WoW emphasizes. Consumables like potions are varying degrees of rare, and don't often heal much. Regular healing in this game requires some kind of resource to be spent, whether it be a whole spell slot or some other resource—for example, a character with the *Healer* feat can use a charge on a Healing Kit to restore hit points to a character, once per rest per character. Typically, healing in this game only heals a relatively small portion of a character's health, and it's pretty rare for any healing ability in the game to take a character near-death and bring them to near-full. Some features (like a Paladin's Lay on Hands) might be capable of doing that, but there aren't many that can do that, and they usually have tough restrictions (using Lay on Hands like that would almost certainly use up all the points they have in an entire adventuring day).

This is all a pretty long way of saying that whatever features do exist in 5th edition D&D to facilitate this kind of playstyle aren't going to be very strong, and they definitely aren't going to be as strong as the mechanics that WoW facilitates, where characters are expected to go to 1hp back up to full back to 1hp back to full many times in a single raid encounter.

So, having said all of that:

### Option 1: Necromancy Wizards

Starting at level 2, Necromancy Wizards gain the ability to drain health from opponents whenever they deal a killing blow with a [non-cantrip] spell.

> #### Grim Harvest
>
> At 2nd level, you gain the ability to reap life energy from creatures you kill with your spells. Once per turn when you kill one or more creatures with a spell of 1st level or higher, you regain hit points equal to twice the spell's level, or three times its level if the spell belongs to the School of Necromancy. You don't gain this benefit for killing constructs or undead.

Since Necromancy Wizards now have an incentive to focus on Necromantic spells when dealing damage, a playstyle that focuses on trying to gauge the remaining hitpoints of a creature and unloading a powerful spell designed to knock out one or more of your enemy creatures and quickly restore some of your own Hitpoints. This feature scales to a limited degree with player level, since higher level spells will restore more hitpoints. So a playstyle that maximizes use of this feature will take some of the burden off any other characters that emphasize healing output.

### Option 2: Grave Cleric

At level 17, Grave-domain Clerics gain a feature that permits the cleric to heal their allies for a non-trivial amount of damage whenever an enemy goes down:

> #### Grave Domain: Keeper of Souls
>
> Starting at 17th level, you can seize a trace of vitality from a parting soul and use it to heal the living. When an enemy you can see dies within 60 feet of you, you or one creature of your choice that is within 60 feet of you regains hit points equal to the enemy's number of Hit Dice. You can use this feature only if you aren't incapacitated. Once you use it, you can't do so again until the start of your next turn.

This ability isn't strictly based on damage output so much as it allows you to guarantee some life regeneration for you or your allies whenever an enemy dies (presumably as the result of damage you and your allies have been dealing to it).

### Option 3: Vampiric Touch

You've already called out that specific example. As a spell, it's accessible to either of the archetypes I've specifically called out (Necromancy Wizards because it's a Wizard spell, and Grave Clerics as a domain spell they get for free). There are a number of spells (usually Necromancy-based) that can be used to regain health while dealing damage, but they are limited by the use of concrete spell slots, which are difficult to recover.

## Overall Conclusion

Either of those options are probably the strongest "Shadow-Priest"-like archetypes available in 5th edition D&D, at least in officially published material. There are Unearthed Arcana options you can explore (the Twilight-circle Druid archetype might be of particular note to you), and you can look for homebrew materials that might cover this niche (D&D transpositions of WoW classes are relatively popular) so you can look for those options as well if you find these options to be unsatisfying.

Answer (score 8):

## Unearthed Arcana's Druid Twilight Circle

Wizards presented some new options for Druids, including the [Twilight Circle](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_Druid11272016_CAWS.pdf). This particular Circle hasn't made it into official publication, but it has a mechanic you might be interested in with **Harvest's Scythe**

> When you roll damage for a spell, you can increase that damage by spending dice from the pool. You can spend a number of dice equal to half your druid level or less. Roll the spent dice and add them to the damage as necrotic damage. If you kill one or more hostile creatures with a spell augmented in this way, you or an ally of your choice that you can see within 30 feet of you regains 2 hit points per die spent to increase the spell’s damage, or 5 hit points per die if at least one of the slain creatures was undead.

Answer (score 3):

## Take Shepherd Druid to use Unicorn Spirit

Once per short or long rest, a 2nd level Circle of the Shepherd Druid can summon a Unicorn Spirit form Spirit Totem, as a bonus action, for 1 minute that:

> "if you cast a spell using a spell slot that restores hit points to any creature inside or outside the aura, each creature of your choice in the aura also regains hit points equal to your druid level"

Casting *Vampiric Touch* should work with this, on the turn you cast it at least, as "you regain hit points equal to half the amount of necrotic damage dealt". A two level Druid dip only heals each companion by 2 hit points, but it has the right feel?

As a Cleric you could also cast *Life Transference* occasionally to spend all the health you have built up with *Vampiric Touch* on one ally all in one go.

If you wanted to have more levels of Shepherd Druid to increase your Spirit Totem healing then you could use the 2nd level *Wither and Bloom* spell which is on the Druid spell list to similar effect. Or persuade your DM to let you take the Strixhaven Witherbloom Student background that would put *Vampiric Touch* on your spell list.